# Adding one Account Object to another Account Object

Tags: java

```
private HashMap<Integer, Account> accountMap;
```

There are account objects inside this map.

What i am trying to do is merging objects by their key lets say add Account 2 object to Account 1 and remove Account 2 from map.

This method is in bank class:

```
public void combineAccounts(int uid1, int uid2) {
Account x = new Account(uid1);

x.add(accountMap.get(uid1),accountMap.get(uid2));



    }
```

Account.class:
a1.getValuables returns list obj : [Value: 16253.0 -> 100.0gr gold]

```
public class Account{

    private final int uid;
    private final List<Valuable> valuables;

    public Account(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
        valuables = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addValuable(Valuable valuable){
        valuables.add(valuable);
    }

    /*implementation of getTotalValue method comes here*/

    public double getTotalValue​(){



return 0;
        //returns total amount of valuables present in that account
    }
public Account add(Account a1,Account a2){
Account mergedaccount;

 mergedaccount = a1.getValuables()+a2.getValuables() // something like this...

return mergedaccount;

}


    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }


    public List<Valuable> getValuables() {
        return valuables;
    }


    public void sortValuables(){
        Collections.sort(valuables);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "uid:" + uid + " " + valuables;
    }
}
```

Bank.class:

```
public class Bank {

    private HashMap<Integer, Account> accountMap;
    private Account merged;
    public Bank() {

        accountMap = new HashMap<>();

    }

    /*implementation of createAccount method comes here*/
    public void createAccount(int uid){

        for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Account> entry : accountMap.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey() == uid){

                throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            }
        }
        accountMap.put(uid,new Account(uid));

 // creates an account of id uid, if that account already exists an exception is thrown


    }


    public Account getAccount(int uid){
        return accountMap.get(uid);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Collection<Account> accounts = accountMap.values();
        return accounts.toString();
    }

    public void addValuable(int uid, Valuable valuable) {
        if(accountMap.get(uid) ==null){

            System.out.println("valuables could not be added, no such account");
            return;
        }else{

            accountMap.get(uid).addValuable(valuable);

        }

        //Add valuable to an existing account, if the account does not exist, an error message should be printed.

    }

    public void combineAccounts(int uid1, int uid2) {
Account x = new Account(uid1);

x.add(accountMap.get(uid1),accountMap.get(uid2));



    }


    public void closeAccount(int uid) {

        if(accountMap.get(uid) != null){
            accountMap.remove(uid);
        }else{

            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Two obligatory comments: 1) What's the question/problem? 2) Please fix the formatting of your code examples, e.g. the intendation and massive amount of empty lines.

Comment: I found something that might resemble a question in your code: 
 `mergedaccount = a1.getValuables()+a2.getValuables() // something like this...` - you should look up how objects generally are cloned/combined in Java. In your case you could create a new account with the same id and then add the lists of valuables to that new account, e.g. via a method `add(List<Valuable> valuables)` which is called like `mergedAccount.add( a1.getValuables() ); mergedAccount.add( a2.getValuables() );`

Comment: question is how do i merge 2 account object into 1